# Log when a thread is waiting on arrival at a lock statement

Tags: c#, locking, system.reactive, task-parallel-library, plinq

Is there a quick way to log that a thread is waiting for a lock when a thread arrives at a

```
lock(x)
{
  //do work on a collection

}
```

?

If thread 1 arrives at the lock, and there isn't another thread in the block, there should be no log.  Then if thread 2 arrives at the lock(x) and thread 1 is still in the block, there should be a log.  The ideal solution would not require switching to a Mutex or Monitor add much complexity.  If there's a quick and easy way to do this using TPL, PLINQ, or RX that would be great.

Comment: I think you'll have to expand the `lock` short-hand to its long-hand equivalent and insert logging manually.

Comment: When I said the ideal solution would not require switching to a Mutex, I really meant it would not require using a Mutex or Monitor explicitly.  I edited the initial question to reflect this.  I do need this just for debugging and want to keep the syntax as simple as possible.

Comment: Then PostSharp is the way to go.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can [de-sugar the `lock` statement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx) and use [Monitor.TryEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289679.aspx) to check if the lock can be acquired without waiting:

```
bool lockTaken = false;
var obj = x;
try
{
    Monitor.TryEnter(obj, ref lockTaken);
    if (!lockTaken)
    {
        Log();
        Monitor.Enter(obj, ref lockTaken);
    }
    //do work on a collection
}
finally
{
    if (lockTaken)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware if any of this changed during this time and if there is a better way to handle this today?

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't be able to do this easily with the standard `lock()` statement. You can use [`Monitor.TryEnter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tssbxcw.aspx) to attempt to enter the lock, and then log something if the method returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you attempting to do this? If it is for debugging or profiling purposes, you could use the unmanaged CLR profiling or debugging API. Another thought would be to statically modify your IL code after compiling using a tool such as PostSharp or Afterthought. (Note that Afterthought cannot do this in its current form, but as you have the source you could hack this in.)

I would recommend that you modify your code instead. I'd recommend this instead of dtb's syntax:

```
if (!Monitor.TryEnter(x))
{
    Log();
    Monitor.Enter(x);
}
try
{
    //do work on a collection
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(x);
}
```